# Should I still use FastMM in Delphi Alexandria?

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I've been using FastMM for very long time always placing 'FastMM4' in all Delphi projects. Does it make sense with the latest Delphi versions?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @DelphiCoder Try what?

Comment: I've been testing deleaker.. not free, but pretty cool.

Comment: @AmigoJack trying, if FastMM still works with D11, of course.

Comment: @DelphiCoder I'm very sure the question does not ask if it **works**, but instead if it **makes sense** (as in: is it still an improvement or even making things slower). It feels like OP is beyond the **try it** part.

Comment: @AmigoJack If the OP had tried it, he could possibly have checked these points himself and could answer himself, if it makes sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It still does make sense, yes.

Delphi c.2007 starting using a version of FastMM4 as the default memory manager - but it [has some stuff removed.](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2370-difference-between-fastmm-4992-and-one-that-comes-with-delphi-103/)

Continue to use the *"real"* version of FastMM.

Comment: Has any one tried the "real" version with 11.1. I was having trouble when I enabled it just the other day. After some messing around I got it to report the errors in the log file, but the stack/trace wording was not showing anything useful (don't have Delphi running at the moment so can't tell you what actually was messed up at this time). It also appears you have to stick with FastMM4, as FastMM5 is a rewrite and doesn't appear to work with 11.1

Comment: Why exactly shouldn't FastMM5 work with 11.1? Spoiler alert: it does work